# Warning an errors after updating to tensorflow 2.1 in AWS Deep Learning AMI

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, amazon-ami

We updated from tensorflow 1.13 to 2.1 in an EC2 instances where we installed the following AMI:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Amazon-Web-Services-Deep-Learning-AMI-Ubuntu-1604/B077GCH38C#pdp-reviews

The AMI was the v24 and therefore contained some packages that needed updated.

I updated the tensorflow package to the version mention before but now everytime that I load the library I get the following error:

[image]

Also it is in possible to run any of the examples available in the documentation as I am getting multiple errors.

Would someone be able to support?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the latest version of the Deep Learning AMI to use TensorFlow 2.1 (release notes here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/appendix-ami-release-notes.html)